# Is there a way to SurfaceArea of each face of 3D shape separately?

Tags: regions, opencascade

Consider the following 3D shape as an example:

```
ClearAll[cylinder];
cylinder[r_,z_]:=Cylinder[{{r,r,0},{r,r,z}},r];
```

It is a cylinder whose entire `SurfaceArea`, I can calculate as follows:

```
Expand@Simplify[SurfaceArea[cylinder[r,z]],Assumptions->z>0]
```

> 2 π r^2 + 2 π r z

But I want something like as follows:

> <|1 -> π r^2, 2 -> 2 π r z, 3 -> π r^2|>

So if I want the total I can do the following:

```
Total[%]
```

I think maybe converting this shape to a `Region` and then applying some built-in function to get the faces of a `3D Region` as separate `2D Regions` would be helpful. Then maybe I can map `Area` on the `2D Regions` to find what I need?

Comment: So in your treatment, a cone will have two faces, and a sphere only one?

Comment: @J.M. yes but remember it should be possible to work with composite shapes. That is the entire goal here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) for this:

```
ClearAll[cylinder];
cylinder[r_, z_] := Cylinder[{{r, r, 0}, {r, r, z}}, r];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
s = OpenCascadeShape[cylinder[1, 2]]
fs = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[s];
bms = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh /@ fs;
#["Wireframe"] & /@ bms
```

[image]

```
Area[MeshRegion[#]] & /@ bms
{12.546193962183768`, 3.121445152258052`, 3.121445152258052`}
```

**Update:**
To refine the mesh, have a look in the documentation on the different methods to specify that. One option is to set the "LinearDeflection".

```
OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[#, 
  "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.001}] &
```

Comment: This is very interesting. What is `OpenCascade`? Is it a separate program? Is it included with `Mathematica` installation? Do I need to install anything extra to make your code work? I don't have access to `Mathematica` right now and will test it when I am home.

Comment: @user13892 Everything is onboard.

Comment: Is there a way/option to get a denser mesh for the faces? The answers for their `Area` are not very accurate.

Comment: @user13892, see update and documentation.